# creating a trigger after update exclude a column?

Tags: sql-server, trigger, update

I want to create a trigger that set a column to to_sync true if the other columns has been changed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[product_trig]
  ON dbo.product
  AFTER UPDATE
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT UPDATE (to_sync) 
      BEGIN
          UPDATE dbo.product 
              SET  to_sync  = 'TRUE'
          FROM dbo.product INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON dbo.product.NAME = i.NAME
      END
END
```

the above code  raise an error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure mat_trig, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
Msg 140, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Can only use IF UPDATE within a CREATE TRIGGER statement.
Time: 0.504s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your code is missing or is typo'ed

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[product_trig]
  ON dbo.product
  AFTER UPDATE
AS -- you miss this 'as'
BEGIN -- you miss this 'begin'
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT UPDATE (to_sync) 
      BEGIN
          UPDATE dbo.product 
              SET  to_sync  = 'TRUE'
          FROM dbo.product INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON dbo.product.NAME = i.NAME
      END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You were really close. Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[product_trig]
  ON dbo.product
  AFTER UPDATE
  AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT UPDATE (to_sync) 
      BEGIN
          UPDATE dbo.product 
              SET  to_sync  = 'TRUE'
          FROM dbo.product INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON dbo.product.NAME = i.NAME
      END
```

I believe you had one too many `END` statements plus you needed the `AS` piece on line 4.

[Here is another stack overflow answer where someone tried to do something similar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314582/is-if-not-updatecolumn-valid-syntax)

Comment: Msg 2714, Level 16, State 2, Procedure product_trig, Line 1
    There is already an object named 'product_trig' in the database.
    Msg 140, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    Can only use IF UPDATE within a CREATE TRIGGER statement.
    Time: 0.504s

Comment: Based on that error, I would assume you need to change it from a `CREATE` to an `ALTER`, jyao also had a viable solution that looks like it met your needs.